# Responsive bootstrap form not becoming responsive

Tags: html, forms, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to build a form using bootstrap and need it to be responsive too. That is it needs to go from 4 colmn layout to 3 to 1 colmn layout deepending on width.

My code is located at http://jsfiddle.net/AzMz2/1/
*updated with fluid* **STILL NOT WORKING**

You will notice that initially I have this as 4 columns. However, when I resize, it doesn't become 3 column. I need this to become 3 column and then as widths decreases to 2 and then to 1 column (aka responsiveness).  Also the columns need to align vertically and horizontally. That is also not happening. What am I doing wrong? I can not seem to figure out. Thanks in advance.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="submitDetails" acttion="#">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group oneLine">
      <label class="control-label" for="custom1">1. Did you telephone us?</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio span2" for="">
          <input name="custom1" id="custom1" value="Yes" checked="checked" type="radio">
          Yes </label>
        <label class="radio span2" for="">
          <input name="custom1" id="custom1" value="No" type="radio">
          No </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group  oneLine">
      <label class="control-label" for="custom2">2. How did you hear about us?</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="1" checked="checked" type="radio">
            Newspaper </label>
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="2" type="radio">
            Billboard </label>
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="3" type="radio">
            Yellow Pages </label>
          <label class="radio span3 " for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="4" type="radio">
            Radio </label>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="5" type="radio">
            Google / Internet </label>
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="23" type="radio">
            White Pages </label>
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="7" type="radio">
            Referral </label>
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="8" type="radio">
            Television </label>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="9" type="radio">
            Familiar with area </label>
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="10" type="radio">
            Magazine </label>
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="21" type="radio">
            Catalogue </label>
          <label class="radio span3" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="25" type="radio">
            Our website </label>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <label class="radio inline" for="">
            <input name="custom2" id="custom2" value="24" type="radio">
            1300 Number </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<br/>
<div align="right"><button>SUBMIT</button></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>


    <style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.oneLine .controls {
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
.control-group.oneLine > label {

    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.error {
    color: #ff0000;
}
.radio.inline{
    margin-bottom:auto;
    vertical-align: auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the css you are using on your jsFiddle, and on your span2 / span3 classes, you are using [Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) .

Unless you want to use custom CSS, this version of Bootstrap doesn't offer the option of moving from 4 to 3 to 2 to 1 column as the viewport decreases. Four columns will simply collapse to one column at viewports below 768px.

Have you considered using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com)?

It has replaced the old .spanX classes with new options like .col-sm-X and .col-md-Y which will let you do what you describe.  See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid for full details.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David. I will have to look at the spec a bit more carefully. Glancing at the bootstrap3 spec, it seems like it is what I am looking for. What a way to spend Saturday :)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="submitDetails" acttion="#">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group ">
          <label class="control-label" for="custom2">2. How did you hear about us?</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="">
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="1" checked="checked" type="radio">Newspaper</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="2" type="radio">Billboard</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="3" type="radio">Yellow Pages</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="4" type="radio">Radio</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="5" type="radio">Google / Internet</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="23" type="radio">White Pages</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="7" type="radio">Referral</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="8" type="radio">Television</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="9" type="radio">Familiar with area</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="10" type="radio">Magazine</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="21" type="radio">Catalogue</label>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="25" type="radio">Our website</label>
              <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
              <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
              <label class="radio col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <input name="custom2" value="24" type="radio">1300 Number</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <button>SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks. It seems to have worked in test... Code added for anyone to use in future

Comment: Looks good @Himu You will find that with Bootstrap 3 the .container-fluid div has been dropped and you use .container . There's a good summary of this 'Mobile First' practice at http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa Thanks a lot. I have a question though. Bootstrap3 does not support Ie7 right...? :( Is there any workaround for IE7?

Comment: officially support for IE7 has been dropped. THis might work for you, haven't tried it myself though: https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7  . Good luck!

Comment: `Turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout by changing your outermost .container to .container-fluid` ~ [Source](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). Looks like **`class="container-fluid"`** is back to the business in `3.1`.